# .contains() not working with BufferedReader

Tags: java, file, while-loop, bufferedreader

i am trying to create a program that checks a file and prints lines back to me if they contain the word "TRUE"

here is the file contents

```
TRUE,TRUE
FALSE,TRUE
FALSE,FALSE
TRUE,FALSE
TRUE,TRUE
TRUE,FALSE
```

here is the program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "C:\\Users\\tree3\\Desktop\\Programming\\file.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            
            if(line.contains("TRUE")) { 
                System.out.println(line);
                // read next line
                line = reader.readLine();
            } else {
                System.out.println("false");
            }
            
            
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
```

the program just prints `false` indefinitely

why is this?

Comment: Notic that if a line doesn't contain the word `TRUE`, you're not reading the next line. You should move the following statement to the end of the `while` loop: `line = reader.readLine();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\tree3\\Desktop\\Programming\\file.txt"))) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            if (line.contains("TRUE")) {
                System.out.println(line);
            } else {
                System.out.println("false");
            }
            // read next line
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Do not read next line in side an if statement. What if the if statement is not true? You will never go ahead and be stuck on that line indefinitely.

Use try-with-resources (Java 7+) and don't worry about closing resources.

---

Cleaner (Java 8+):

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\tree3\\Desktop\\Programming\\file.txt"))) {
    reader.lines().forEach(line -> System.out.println(line.contains("TRUE")));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```